# How to use inherited flag in Shopware 6 for OneToOneAssociationField

Tags: shopware

I have a new OneToOneAssociationField in the ProductDefinition with a product extension which has Inherited() as an additional flag. The EntityDefinition of the counterpart also has a OneToOneAssociationField with ReverseInherited() flag. If I save the main product, the foreign key "testproductextension_id" for this product is correct filled in. But the Inheritance column, has only the id of the parent element, this happens for the parent element as well as for all child elements. If I now manually exchange this id with the "testproductextension_id", the additional data is loaded for the child element as well. This means that as far as I can detect my problem myself, not "testproductextension_id" but the "product_id" will be saved in "testproductextension", does anyone know why this happens?

```
//ProductExtension
    $collection->add(
        (new FkField('testproductextension_id', 'vrdataId', TestProductExtensionDefinition::class))->addFlags(new Inherited())
    );

    $collection->add(
        (new OneToOneAssociationField(
            'testproductextension',
            'testproductextension_id',
            'id',
            TestProductExtensionDefinition::class,
            false
        ))->addFlags(new Inherited())
    ); 


    //TestProductExtensionDefinition
     return new FieldCollection([
        (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new Required(), new PrimaryKey()),
        (new StringField('testname', 'testname'))->addFlags(),

        (new OneToOneAssociationField('product', "product_id","id",ProductDefinition::class,false))
            ->addFlags(new ReverseInherited('testproductextension')),
    ]);
```

Comment: Did you solve this yet?

Comment: unfortunately not